# What will happen if same hyperparameter got defined both in pipeline and GridsearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have defined the hyperparameter of a model in my pipeline and the  algorithm might use GridsearchCV on execution and if it does so what will happen to the hyperparameter defined previously in the pipeline

Pipeline

```
pipe_nusvc = Pipeline([('clfnu', NuSVC(nu=0.5,kernel='rbf'))])
```

I can add Parameters using

```
pipe_nusvc['clfnu'].cache_size=300
```

And i thought about removing the added cache_size from the pipeline
If GridsearchCV is used

If GridsearchCV is used ,the cache_size=300 defined in the pipeline will still remain there and there is no solution to remove it during running,  so what will happen if same hyperparameter is being defined both in pipeline and GridsearchCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "remove" `cache_size`; it is a parameter of the `NuSVC` object. You can reset it to the default, but 200 is already the default.

If you set a value for a parameter (whether at initialization, using `set_params`, or manually as you have written), then that overrides the default, and it will stay that way until you change it.

`sklearn` has a utility called "clone": a new estimator of the same type is returned, with the same parameters set, but with none of the fitted/learned attributes.

In a grid search, the estimator (pipeline in this case) is cloned, and each clone gets assigned one of the parameter combinations (overriding anything you may have set before).  So if you set `cache_size` in the definition of the pipeline, or later as in your code, but you also set `cache_size` in the grid search, only the grid values will matter.  The original pipeline, outside the grid search, will continue to exist independently and have your set `cache_size`, but the search's `cv_results_` and `best_estimator_` won't.  On the other hand, if you don't have `cache_size` in your parameter grid, then whatever value you set beforehand will be used for *every* parameter combination in the search.

Comment: @ Ben Reiniger I know that, what i meant is to remove what i added, in my pipeline i added the cache_size size into the model and i want to remove it

Comment: You can see that i added it using ```pipe_nusvc['clfnu'].cache_size=300``` im looking for a similar way for the removal

Comment: @Ctrl7 as said clearly in the answer, there is no such thing as "removal" of a hyperparameter; even if you had **not** included it explicitly in your pipeline, it would still be there, with the default value of 200 (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.NuSVC.html)). Only thing you can do is to reset it to its default value with `pipe_nusvc['clfnu'].cache_size=200`.

Comment: @Ben Reiniger thank you for your response..! , my algorithm based on conditions might use GridsearchCV if it does so , the cache value mentioned before in the model(in pipeline) will remain there,  so the cache_size is defined 2 times one in the model(in pipeline) and in Gridsearchcv , like you mentioned i could set it to a default value , but what could be implications that can arise from defining cache_size 2 times ? (Note once the program is running i cant stop it and change values and rerun , that's why asked this question ,inorder to change/remove values pragmatically)

Comment: Similarly if we dont include cache_size in pipeline and define some values via GridsearchCV , will that default value (200) be still there in the pipeline?